# create constructor for a class extending JsonRequest<JSONObject>

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have created a class in android studio which extends JsonRequest
but android studio gives me an error and wants me to create a constructor because there is no default constructor in the library (volley library) for that.
Actually I'm using volley library to parse a json file in a listview in android.
Cause the json is all Persian text I have created this class to change it to utf-8 encoding.
Please show me how the needed constructor should be like. I have tried some but wasn't correct.

```
public class Utf8JsonRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {
    ...
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse (NetworkResponse   response) {
        try {
            String utf8String = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(utf8String),   HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log error
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // log error
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't the persian text already encoded in utf-8?

Comment: @nandsito by default the volley library's encoder is ISO-8859-1 and it can't show persian or arabic text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a constructor:

```java
// the constructor should have at least these parameters
// to be passed onto super()
public Utf8JsonRequest(int method,
                       String url,
                       String requestBody,
                       Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                       Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, requestBody, listener, errorListener);

    // you can initialize other stuff if you wish
}
```

Comment: tank you @nandsito

Answer (score 0):

It is the same constructor as JsonRequest :

JsonRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)

Comment: Well it has to, it is in the docs http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonRequest.html

Comment: tanx for your attention